# Adding a padding to a JavaFX button with an image

Tags: java, javafx-2

Why can't add a padding **left** to the image inside the `#todo` button ?

[image]

```
.button {           
    -fx-background-size: 18 18;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;       
    -fx-background-position:left;   
    -fx-padding:20;
    /* same as -fx-label-padding:20; */
}

#todo {
    -fx-background-image: url("../images/Knob Add.png");
}
```

Comment: As I've observed CSS ref, it is API... If you have suggestions, you can file an RFE in jfx-jira.

Comment: @AlexanderKirov well, first time with jira, https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30842 , wonder if I'm doing it right.

Comment: All right. Waiting for developers answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use backgrounds to add images to your button, instead set a graphic on the button.

```
#todo .button {           
    -fx-padding: 20px;
    -fx-graphic: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle-addon1/16/text-plus-icon.png"); 
     /* Icon License: CC Attribution-Noncommercial-No Derivate 3.0 http://www.iconarchive.com/show/circle-addon1-icons-by-martz90/text-plus-icon.html*/
}
```

[image: paddedtodo]

**Background information on Backgrounds and Margins**

Backgrounds cover the entire background of a region, including the padded area, so you can't position a background using padding.  Backgrounds are also a lot trickier than style with css and configure than graphics (as you found out...).  You could get some approximation of what you want by setting -fx-background-position property and also adjusting your padding to allow for the background area of your background image so that your button text content doesn't overwrite the background.  But it is fiddly and not worth it when it can be done in a much more straightforward way using a graphic.

I recall some conversation among developers about adding a margin property.  If such a property were added, the background would not spill into the margin but be encapsulated by it.  Such a property is not in Java 7 though,

**Related Question**

[JavaFX - create custom button with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518458/javafx-create-custom-button-with-image)