# Javafx Image as button

Tags: image, button, javafx

I would like to set an Image as Button, but getting always the following Error:

Bound mismatch: The type MouseEvent is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type EventHandler

```
@FXML ImageView imgReturn;

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    imgReturn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent ev)
                {

                }
    );
```

Comment: See also: [JavaFX - create custom button with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518458/javafx-create-custom-button-with-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your imports.

You are using a wrong `MouseEvent`:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
```

You should use the JavaFX one instead:

```
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
```