# Add pictures in JavaFx Gui

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to add images in the GUI I ve created using JavaFx. My JavaFx is the following:

```
StackPane layoutTSignUp = new StackPane();
layoutTSignUp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFF;");
```

How can I instead of having a color I can add images. Furthermore how can I achieve the same in my buttons:

```
teacherButton.setStyle("-fx-font: 45 Arial; -fx-base: #FFFF");
```

Comment: You second question about images in buttons is duplicate of: [JavaFX - create custom button with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518458/javafx-create-custom-button-with-image)

Answer (score 2):

**Programatically**

For your `StackPane` you can use [BackgroundImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundImage.html) class:

```
BackgroundImage backgroundImage= new BackgroundImage(new Image(getClass().getResource("thinking-man.jpg").toExternalForm(),32,32,false,true),
                BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

stackPane.setBackground(new Background(backgroundImage));
```

For buttons: Buttons have a [graphic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#graphicProperty) property:

```
button.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("thinking-man.jpg").toExternalForm())));
```

**Using CSS**

If you would prefer to use stylesheets to set background images you can use:

**-fx-background-image, -fx-background-repeat, -fx-background-position and -fx-background-size**.

[For details you can read the JavaFX CSS reference for Region class.](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)

Using the same example with `StackPane`:

```
stackPane.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
stackPane.getStyleClass().add("stackpane-with-background");
```

In **application.css**:

```
.stackpane-with-background{
    -fx-background-image: url("thinking-man.jpg");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;   
    -fx-background-size: 900 506;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 30, 0.5, 0, 0); 
}
```

Hope this helps.