# creating custom button in java fxml

Tags: css, javafx, graphics, fxml

How to create a **custom round button** in fxml,I've tried this Code

```
   <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="273.0" 
          layoutY="103.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
          onAction="#next" 
          style="-fx-base:#b6e7c9;
          -fx-font:12 papyrus;
          -fx-border-radius:15px 50px 30px 40px ;
          -fx-border:2px solid;" 
          textOverrun="CLIP">
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look of this
 [4 Using FXML to Create a User Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm)

And this one maybe could help you :)
[JavaFX - create custom button with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518458/javafx-create-custom-button-with-image)